# Hibernate unwanted delete after update in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Here are my entities 
Master:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_project",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"))
    private Set<Project> projects;
```

Slave:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set<Student> students;
```

When I update project, everything seems fine. But when I update student, all relations in the student_project table with the students id are gone.
I think it has something to do with the cascade field in the master table, but I am not sure. How should it look like? Or maybe it is something else?
Btw I merge both entities using em.merge(student) / em.merge(project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owning side of the relationship is `Student`. So when you merge a detached `Student` object, Hibernate will synchronize the `projects` collection with the database. This has nothing to do with cascading. That's just simply the relationship ownership that causes this. If the `projection` of that `Student` you merge are empty, all existing projects from `student_project` will be deleted for that student.

Comment: So, the best approach would be to select all the relationships from the database that contains the id of the object that is updated and append those object from non-owning side to the updated object?

Comment: You don't have to select all relationships. You can just load the `Student` and apply all the basic attributes from the incoming object on that loaded object.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Works like a charm, thank you very much!!